# maven basic project templates

Tags: maven, archetypes

i generally needs that kind  of project.But most maven archetypes generating extra  files,jars ... .How can i create simple template of that kind of projects .

```
       1-jsf2 + JPA
       2-jsf1.2 +JPA
       3-spring +jsf2+JPA
```

Comment: is this question stupid,i know how to develop but getting start take long time , because of configuration .

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple example by line command:

```
  mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

fore more info: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: I think the questioner was asking how to create a new archetype, not how to use existing archetypes.